# How can I accept bank account payments using Stripe API for ACH payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, stripe-payments

The application that i am working on is accepting payments via card. The requiremnt is to acccept payment via bank accounts(ACH payments)

I tried using the payment method option as us_bank_account, but the parameters seems to incorrect here

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
  {
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
    payment_method_types: ['us_bank_account'],
    payment_method_options: {
      us_bank_account: {
        routing_number: 110000000,
        account_number: 123456789,
        account_holder_type:'individual',
      },
    },
  },
)
```

The error I get is

````
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Received unknown parameters: account_holder_type, account_number, routing_number
from /home/admin1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.7/gems/stripe-5.33.0/lib/stripe/stripe_client.rb:650:in `handle_error_response'```
````

I am unsure which API and parameters are required here. Also, can I use Transfer API instead of PaymentIntent. I am avoiding Charge API since it is depreciated.

My goal is to test the API with mt sandbox account (acct_testXXXXXXXXXX) and make payments different account and routing numbers

[Test account and routing number](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment#test-account-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values for `account_holder_type`, `account_number`, and `routing_number` parameters should be sent as part of `payment_method_data.us_bank_account`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_data-us_bank_account

The `payment_method_data` dictionary also requires `type` and US bank accounts require an account holder name. Your creation request should look something like this:

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
  {
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
    payment_method_types: ['us_bank_account'],
    payment_method_data: {
      type: 'us_bank_account',
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Test Name'
      },
      us_bank_account: {
        routing_number: '110000000',
        account_number: '000123456789',
        account_holder_type: 'individual'
      }
    }
  }
)
```

The above will create a PaymentIntent but that PaymentIntent will still need to be confirmed. Confirming a PaymentIntent requires your customer to accept a mandate. I recommend following this guide as you test since you'll ultimately have your customer share bank account information on the frontend instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. 
However, the Payment Intent has not entirely succeeded. Can you please provide some insight 
The PaymentIntent status is: requires_source_action

Comment: You should look at the `next_action` value. I suspect you'll need to complete microdeposit verification next: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API#microdeposit-only-verification

Still, I recommend following the guide from the top and using FinancialConnections for verification instead of microdeposits.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the Source Action as per the suggestion. In case of ACH you need to mimic mirco deposits after sending the the mandate.I used the descriptor code SM11AA and was able to complete the payment